# Single and double elimination algorithm. Tournament bracket placement algorithm

Tags: algorithm, brackets, tournament

I need to develope site with feature create tournament bracket (single and double elimination like this http://challonge.com/tournament/bracket_generator).

I try to solve this problem, but cant figure out how correctly do it. I'm confused. I'm sure I need to use tree for create tournament, fill it with matches, and store all of it at db . But my own ideas are very bad.

I think there are some academical algorithms which solve this problem. Could somebody give me materials (books, literature) about this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Laravel plugin to manage tournament trees creation, you can see it here: https://github.com/xoco70/laravel-tournaments

You will be able to generate single elimination tournaments.

Double elimination is not implemented yet, but at least, you could have a good base to work on it.